# How to repeat dates for multiples values and fill missing dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date, recursion, missing-data

I have a table with date, ID and Values, which looks like this

[image]

I want to repeat the date range(start date, end date) for all IDs, and if the value is missing for any date enter 0.

[image]

How can I achieve this in SQL?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you explain your logic by giving an example?

Comment: I am trying to repeat dates for all ids.  I have data as shown in the first picture. I want to have one date repeated for all ids, like 01-02-2020 for all ids, if id has no value on that date put 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below example in SQL Server.

1. First you need to have a date table with the list of dates.
2. Then, you need to have the combination of date, id values
3. Now, you need to fill the val if it exists for the date, otherwise, it will be 0.

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = '2020-02-01';
SET @ToDate = '2020-02-28';
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE(theDate DATE) 
DECLARE @datasource TABLE(id int, dateVal DATE, Val INT)

-- all days in that period
INSERT INTO @DateTable 
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1) 
  TheDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, @FromDate) AS DATE)
  FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
  WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;

--
INSERT INTO @datasource
VALUES
(59895,'2020-02-01',5),(59895,'2020-02-03',7),
(59888,'2020-02-01',2),(59888,'2020-02-02',10)

;WITH CTE_idDates AS
(
SELECT theDate,id FROM @DateTable
CROSS JOIN 
@datasource
)
SELECT theDate, id,
COALESCE((SELECT Val from @dataSource WHERE dateval=c.thedate and id=c.id),0)
FROM CTE_idDates AS c
```

**Result set**

```
+------------+-------+------------------+
|  theDate   |  id   | (No column name) |
+------------+-------+------------------+
| 2020-02-01 | 59895 |                5 |
| 2020-02-02 | 59895 |                0 |
| 2020-02-03 | 59895 |                7 |
| 2020-02-04 | 59895 |                0 |
| 2020-02-05 | 59895 |                0 |
| 2020-02-06 | 59895 |                0 |
.
.
.
| 2020-02-28 | 59895 |                0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 59888 |                2 |
| 2020-02-02 | 59888 |               10 |
.
.
.
| 2020-02-26 | 59888 |                0 |
| 2020-02-27 | 59888 |                0 |
| 2020-02-28 | 59888 |                0 |
+------------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: It worked great. Thank you so much.  What do I need to do to add the final result to a temp table to use it for another query?

Comment: you can load into a temp table and use it another query if you want. Or you can go for another CTE  and use the CTE in another query

Comment: I am trying to load last CTE in temp table but  I an confused how c.thedate and c.id works. Can you share query to create a temp table for last result. It would really help me.

Comment: Whatever I have used, I have put in the answer. try to derive your case from the answer

Comment: @kulvir . . . This is way more complicated than necessary.  Temporary tables are not needed for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select i.id, t.date, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct date from t) left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.date = i.date;
```

You can use `insert into` or `select into` to put this data into another table.

Comment: But, I think we still need to have date table. without date table, there could be missing dates, where none of the ids have got values. With date table, I think your solution would be fine.

Comment: @VenkataramanR . . . In the question, all dates are represented.

Comment: Got it. I thought it needs for whole month. thanks.

Comment: @VenkataramanR . . . Your answer works.  I just answered because it seemed unnecessarily complicated.  Even if the OP needs to generate the dates and has no numbers or calendar table, that can still be done in a single query.